# PHPMailer was woking fine for a while and then: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (10060) ERROR: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Phpmailer suddenly throwed this message when it was working fine a week ago: "SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: {stuff in spanish talking about timeout, or error receiving answer} (10060) ERROR: SMTP connect() failed."

I've tried the next:

1. Increase timeout var to 60 seconds
2. Modify the ports used inside the script: 25, 26, 587
3. Check that those ports were open in firewall and fortinet
4. Switch between using and not using SSL/TLS (and specific port 465)
5. Uncomment php.ini line about SSL and restart (very commented as a solution)
6. Check, of course, user, password, and mail server

My enviroment:

1. Local server manages PHP (and webpage)
2. Remote provider manages SMTP server
3. Provider is working fine with Outlook
4. Script is working fine in localhost (my pc's, not the server one)

My code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 4;
$mail->Timeout =60; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com.mx";
$mail->Username = "name@domain.com.mx";
$mail->Password = "123456";
$mail->Port = 26;
```

NOTE: We couldn't test telnet because is blocked in server but when testing ping it responded the correct IP

Any walktrought?

Comment: ping will only tell you if a machine's on and responding to ICMP packets. It won't tell you anything about the status of a service (e.g. smtp) on the machine. You'll need to figure out SOME way to test the ports on the remote end. e.g. try fsockopen() to the various email ports and see what happens there.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB It is a good idea to use fsockopen. I get the same error by this way: _10060::Error occurred while requesting data_

Comment: The usual explanations for this are that the server is down, DNS failure or firewall blocks. Using fsockopen is no different to what PHPMailer is doing anyway. It's worth removing PHP from the mix - try telnetting to the various ports. If that doesn't work, PHP won't either.

Comment: Is it possible that your host suddenly started blocking ports that are commonly used for SMTP (such as 25, 587, etc)?  Some hosts (e.g. godaddy) are notorious for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, @MarcB, @Synchro and you were right: ping were not useful to troubleshoot this. Telnet and tracert are beter tools.

And yes @mti2935, In fact, it was a blocked IP, but it was not easy to detect because the rest of the services were working OK.

Hosting provider unblocked our IP and added it to a whitelist (beacuse is a fixed one).

Thanks all of you!